# What is the easiest way to run a boot level surface scan?

Tags: boot, dell-poweredge, hard-drive, diagnostic

I have a PowerEdge 1850 running two SCSI Ultra 320 drives (10k 73gb).  I am looking for recommendations on boot disks / methods to run a boot time surface scan.  I would like to do this at boot time because I have lots of drives to test and don't want to install an OS on all of them.

I am also looking for a fairly generic solution that is not tied to a particular drive brand.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to spend any money, download a Linux livecd (my favorite http://www.sysresccd.org/), and run [badblocks](http://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks).

- Non destructive read and write test, `badblocks -c 2048 -sn /dev/sdi`

  - this will re-write every block.
- **Destructive** read and write test `badblocks -c 2048 -sw /dev/sde`
- Read only test `badblocks -c 2048 -s /dev/sde`

The -c option tells it to operate on more then 1 block at a time, which allows it to run faster.  If you have lots of memory then larger values will help.  On my 1GB system I typically use `-c 10240`.

Comment: Agreed 'badblocks -s -w $THE_DISK' is a great way to test storage before deploying it.

Comment: badblocks is a good tool for doing a quick & dirty scan of the disk, but if it identifies something bad, it doesn't try & recover the underlying data.  It just marks the block as bad & moves on.  (which may be all you want)

Comment: If you wanted to get the underlying data, then you would fire up `dd_rescue` or other recovery tools, also available on the most linux livecds.

Answer (score 0):

There's always a chance for issues with raid-controllers... in that without an OS and drivers, there is no way to access the disks.  Sometimes, (on good controllers anyway) the raid-controller will operate in some sort of simple-mode until the drivers are loaded, and then you will be able to use the full feature-set of the raid controller.   If this is the case, you can use almost any bootable disk tools to do almost anything to the disks.

I highly recommend looking at [GRC's spinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) as it's probably the best tool for doing surface scans & recovery.  It's completely OS agnostic, so it doesn't matter if you're using windows or linux or whatever flavor of OS/file-system/whatever on that disk.  They have ISO bootable images as well as thumb-drive based images you can use to boot directly into the tool without an existing OS on the machine as well.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend SpinRite. http://groups.google.com/group/comp.dcom.xdsl/msg/9aeee32323c2978e?dmode=source&hl=en

Comment: @sciurus  You really shouldn't read the rantings of one uninformed user that really doesn't understand what the tool does.  It's not magic... there's actual practical science behind how it works.

Comment: There are many sources online that document why Steve Gibson lacks credibility. http://allthatiswrong.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/steve-gibson-is-a-fraud/ is a good starting place.

Comment: @sciurus Not really a good starting place for anything other than an argument leading to nowhere.  Your comments are off-topic, and unrelated.  Your only comment *about* SpinRite is more than 10 years old, and was made by a single person who has already demonstrated that he has a personal vendetta against Steve Gibson.

Comment: In that first link, it states that SpinRite *is* 10% legitimate, and I believe that for the purposes of what the OP wants to do (scan for bad sectors) is something that it can do credibly, even 10 years ago.

Comment: I didn't want to start an argument, I just wanted to provide an explanation for a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try SpinRite from http://www.grc.com

Comment: lol... beat you to it :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the PowerEdge diagnostics from Dell? These are usually accessible from the POST screen, and can also be downloaded as a CD image from [Dell's support site](http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R131805&formatcnt=0&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=178684) (double-check the version and its compatibility with your server).

Otherwise SpinRite is a great generic tool as others have already suggested.